# Database model with condition foreign key

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I need to model a database with these conditions:

- One table for `Projects`
- Another table for `Programmers`
- A Programmer can be `Senior` or `Junior`
- Each project may have several Programmers but **at least** one Senior must exist.

I would like to define some kind of conditional foreign key to assure that of all programmers included into a project at least one of them is senior. Also no senior programmer could be downgraded to junior although the opposite can occur.

I don't know how to create this kind of constraints without resorting to some business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you do have to rely on some business logic to achieve what you want.

You can constrain the attribute for Senior and Junior to those two values but you cannot display the upgrade feature on the table level.

What you want is basically a trigger that checks certain constraints but Access does not support database triggers. A workaround is to make the senior-junior-attribute only alterable in a form. In this form you connect an AfterUpdate-event or BeforeUpdate-event to the textbox which is bound to the attribute and check the business logic via VBA-code.

The same goes for your at-least-one-senior-constraint.

Would some code help even further?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it works out to think of having two different constraints rather than one constraint with special conditions.

For example, condition 1: each project must have a senior programmer assigned to it; condition 2: each project may have any number of additional programmers, senior or junior, assigned to it.

```
create table Programmers(
    ID     counter constraint PK_Programmers primary key,
    Name   text,
    Seniority char( 1 ) check( Seniority in( 'S', 'J' ),
    ...,
    constraint UQ_Programmer_seniority unique( ID, Seniority ),
    constraint CK_Programmer_Seniority check( Seniority in( 'S', 'J' ))
);
create table Project(
    ID     counter constraint PK_Projects primary key,
    Name   text,
    SrProg int,
    SrFlag char( 1 ) default 'S',
    ...,
    constraint SK_Project_SrFlag check( SrFlag = 'S' ),
    constraint FK_Project_SrProgrammer foreign key( SrProg, SrFlag )
        references Programmers( ID, Seniority )
 );
```

So the senior programmer is a 1-1 FK defined as part of the project tuple. The reference cannot be made unless the programmer is defined as 'S' (senior) and once the reference is made, the 'S' for that programmer cannot be changed to 'J'.

As for the other programmers, use a standard intersection table. As the seniority of these programmers are not important, just use the PK in the reference.

```
create table Project_Programmers(
    ProjID    int not null,
    ProgID    int not null,
    constraint PK_Project_Programmers primary key( ProjID, ProgID ),
    constraint FK_Project_Programmers_Project foreign key( ProjID )
        references Projects( ID ),
    constraint FK_Project_Programmers_Programmer foreign key( ProgID )
        references Programmers( ID )
);
```

Because the seniority indicator is not part of these FKs, a seniority indicator of 'J' can be changed to 'S' with no problem or from 'S' to 'J' if that programmer is not defined as the mandatory senior programmer of a project. Let's face it, sometimes people have to be demoted. This gives you the additional protection of keeping demoted programmers assigned as *the* senior programmer of any project. The demotion cannot take place until they have been removed from all such positions.